# window.event alternative in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I see that `window.event` or `event` does not work in Firefox, so I need alternative for this. I don't want to set ANY HTML attributes, just Javascript.
I'm within this function and I want to get mouse coordinates from here:

```
document.onmouseover = function(){
    var mouseX = event.clientX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY;
}
```

Obviously this won't work in firefox, so I want to know how to do it.

Comment: Why is this question marked down? It's a reasonable programming question with a simple answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the typical approach that you'll find in examples everywhere.

```
document.onmouseover = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;

    var mouseX = event.clientX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY;
}
```

The W3C standard way of retrieving the `event` object is via the first function parameter. Older IE didn't support that approach, so `event` will be `undefined`. The `||` operator lets us fetch the `window.event` object in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`window.event` (which you're referring to) is a global object that isn't available in all browsers.

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt){
    var mouseX = evt.clientX;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY;
}, false);
```

Comment: Good, but that code won't work on Internet Explorer 8 or lower (which the questioner may have to support).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that's true. I was a bit "blind" to answer only firefox specific issue. OP: see window.attachEvent (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx) for older IE support.

Comment: The answer is good to the specificity of the question, I would add that IE8 comment to the answer though

Comment: @SmaxSmaxović: Too slow? How did you arrive at that conclusion?