# Detect mouse click on element of particular class in Twitter typeahead rendered suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I have an input to which I have tied the Twitter Typeahead plugin and am returning a template for each suggestion. The template contains a tags with links to facebook/twitter/homepages etc, therefore I want to distinguish between the selection of the suggestion itself, or a link contained within that suggestion.

I have a solution that works in Chrome/IE:

```
$(typeahead).on('typeahead:selected',(obj, datum) => {
    if ($(event.target).attr("class").indexOf("typeaheadlink") === -1) { 
       Redirect(datum.entityType + "-view/" + datum.id);
    }
})
```

This basically detects whether the element clicked has a class of `typeaheadlink`, and if so don't redirect to that record in our system, simply open a tab and browse to the external resource.

However, Firefox does not recognise `window.event` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813153/window-event-alternative-in-firefox) and as such I need an alternative solution. Usually I would pass the event as a parameter to the function however the plugin doesn't allow for that.

Without amending the plugin, is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Could you show us the HTML part for the links inside the suggestions? I am feeling that registering a click event listener for those elements should be enough