# Why do you need to pass event for onClick in firefox but not for chrome using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

In firefox you have to pass in event for the following to work

```
// In directive link
function linkFunc(scope, element, attr){
        element.on('click', function(event){

            event.stopPropagation();
            scope.myVar.value = false;
            scope.$digest();
        });
]
```

In Chrome you can do the following

```
// In directive link
function linkFunc(scope, element, attr){
        // Won't work for firefox
        //    will run into ReferenceError: event is not defined
        element.on('click', function(){

            event.stopPropagation();
            scope.myVar.value = false;
            scope.$digest();
        });
}
```

What is the reason behind this behavior discrepancy?

Comment: from where `$event` you are taking?

Comment: 1) are you sure you're writing angular? 2) `$event` is probably undefined which is going to throw a `ReferenceError` exception.

Comment: Sorry I miss type a `$` , but angular work in chrome without event explicitly passed in. The code is inside angular's directive link

Comment: you use ng-click on a button ?

Comment: @AlainIb Its in directive link function, so it has reference to element already

Comment: Okey. from which directive ?

Comment: nothing to deal with angular!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not relative to angularjs or any other framework.

`event` is a global variable in IE & Chrome (property of the `window` object). Not the case in Firefox, so you need to send it explicitly as an argument

Take a look at [this answer](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/window-event-is-not-working-in-firefox/2338) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813153/window-event-alternative-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

there is no "onClick" on angular but "ng-click", (maybe it is Jquery i don't know)

Offical documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

```
<ANY
  ng-click="functionA()">
  ...
</ANY>
```